# Wordpress : Allow to see contents of directory

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, directory

I'm struggling with allowing to see the contents of one specific directory in my Wordpress site, to be seen by anyone. I have already tried creating a .htaccess file in there with the line (Options +Indexes) however I still get a 403 Forbidden error.

http://travelingonrails.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Stations

Anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: The link is forbidden (403) for me.

Comment: Exactly... so how do I solve that :)

Comment: look in the error log of Apache to know what appends.

Comment: The Wordpress htaccess routes all traffic to that directory to the index.php file from there it runs through Wordpress.  If you want it to behave like a typcical lamp directory when accessed from a browser, you will need to write an htaccess rule that tells it to ignore that folder.  But really, why do you want to do this?  There may be a better way to accomplish what you are hoping for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently due to safety reasons this is not allowed and also highly not recommended. Therefore I will look for an alternative approach.